# How to calculate two dataframe'value with scala in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I hava two dataframe ,the count of two dataframe is same,I want to get the sum of each value in two dataframe
this is input:

```
+---+  and       +---+
|df1|            |df2|
+---+            +---+
| 11|            |  1|
| 12|            |  2|
| 13|            |  3|
| 14|            |  4|
| 15|            |  5|
| 16|            |  6|
| 17|            |  7|
| 18|            |  8|
| 19|            |  9|
| 20|            | 10|
+---+            +---+
```

this is my code:

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(1 to 10,2).toDF("df1")
    val df2 = sc.parallelize(11 to 20,2).toDF("df2")
    val df3=df1.rdd.zip(df2.rdd).map(x=>{
      x._1.getInt(0)+x._2.getInt(0)
    }).toDF("result")
    df3.show()
```

the result is:

```
+-----+
|result|
+-----+
|   12|
|   14|
|   16|
|   18|
|   20|
|   22|
|   24|
|   26|
|   28|
|   30|
+-----+
```

I have to change dataframe to rdd then zip two rdd,how to calculate two dataframe with not transform to rdd?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `Window` function to create `row_number` for joining both `dataframes`. After joining just sum the two columns .

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = sc.parallelize(1 to 10,2).toDF("df1")
val df2 = sc.parallelize(11 to 20,2).toDF("df2")

df1.withColumn("rowNo", row_number() over Window.orderBy("df1"))
  .join(df2.withColumn("rowNo", row_number() over Window.orderBy("df2")), Seq("rowNo"))
  .select(($"df1"+$"df2").alias("result"))
  .show(false)
```

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: window will change partition,if i use window I have to repartition when i calculated it

Comment: Yes Window function will definitely change partition. Without accumulating all of your data in one partition how would you make sure that 11 from df2 and 1 from df1 are on the same executor. We can't join two dataframes without making sure all partitions are on the same executor. Your requirement is like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [monotonically_increasing_id()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#monotonically_increasing_id()) to give an id for both dataframe and join with adding two columns.

```
import spark.implicits._
val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(11 to 20).toDF("df1")
val df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize((1 to 10 )).toDF("df2")

df1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
  .join(df2.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id()), "id")
  .withColumn("result", ($"df1" + $"df2")).drop("id").show
```

Output:

```
+---+---+------+
|df1|df2|result|
+---+---+------+
| 11|  1|    12|
| 18|  8|    26|
| 17|  7|    24|
| 20| 10|    30|
| 16|  6|    22|
| 12|  2|    14|
| 14|  4|    18|
| 19|  9|    28|
| 13|  3|    16|
| 15|  5|    20|
+---+---+------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I hope this helped !